# Cortana skills bot invocation name not being discovered after publishing

Tags: botframework, publish

I added a new Bot i am developing in .net via the Bot Channels Registration option in Azure. I then added a Cortana channel to the bot via the Knowledge Store. Although I can test my Bot using Test in Web Chat, I cannot get Cortana to talk to my Bot. When Cortana does understand my accent she just opens up a web page and my break point in my code is never reached. Looking at the Channels Tab in Azure and clicking on edit for the Cortana channel, I see my invocation name as being My_XYZ and the option to edit this is disabled. However in the knowledge store I can edit the invocation name which I have changed to My ABC (with space).

The bot is currently published to Self for testing and I can see that its ID points to the name of my bot in Azure i.e. some_team.my_xyz

I am using a secure ngrok tunnel on my localhost and this works ok as stated with the chat bot.

Does anyone know if there is a step missing from the docs? (some links in the docs give 404 errors) and why i cannot change the invocation name of my bot in Azure. Also do I need to have the same invocation names in the Bot and the Cortana channel or does Cortana handle this mapping for you.

Comment: `cannot change the invocation name of my bot in Azure` Do you mean that you can not edit/change **Invocation name** on Azure portal while you configure Cortana channel?

Comment: I cannot change my Invocation name in the Azure Portal - the field is disabled. However, I have found that I can change it in the knowledge store if i edit the Publish to Self option. The invocation name here gets reflected in the Cortana settings in Azure portal. However Cortana still does not recognise my invocation name. Any ideas how to debug this?

Comment: I deleted everything in the Azure portal and the Knowledge Store and started again. This time I have an Invocation name of My ABC in the Knowledge Store Publish to Self and in the Azure Channels section for Cortana my invocation name is MyABC and i cannot get the two names to be the same. I am assuming both invocations names have to be the same for Cortana to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> I see my invocation name as being My_XYZ and the option to edit this is disabled.

I find that if I’m an ***administrator*** on the subscription, the `Invocation name` option is editable.

[image]

But if I’m use another account with ***Owner*** role, the `Invocation name` option will be disabled. I’m not sure if it is portal issue, if possible, you can try to report it on Azure portal.

> do I need to have the same invocation names in the Bot and the Cortana channel or does Cortana handle this mapping for you.

Based on my experience, we need not to specify same invocation name on Azure Bot portal and Knowledge Store portal.

In my test, I set invocation name with “`helloworld`” (not same as invocation name on Azure Bot portal “**helloworldchat**”), I can invoke `helloworld` as expected.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you can not invoke your skill, you can follow the steps in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/test-debug#troubleshooting-tips) to troubleshoot issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This may seem like a silly question but how to I change roles. I cannot find any option to do this within Azure. I created my free account using my own credit card so that should automatically give me Admin role?

Comment: Do you check the role of your account? You can [see your permissions by click **My permissions**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/om4tM.png) on right top corner of Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved here on Github  https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3991

To sum it up, Cortana Skills is currently only available to the US and since I live in the UK I will have to wait until MS decide to release it to the rest of the world. To overcome this you can change the region of your PC to the US. This allows you to test your app. However, note that Cortana does not fully support adaptive cards.

I only hope that Bot development does not go the same way as apps for Windows 10 did and that MS update the desktop and Azure emulators to support the latest development versions of adaptive cards etc quicker than they are and to release Cortana Skills to developers outside the US. I was hoping that the bot framework would use the same model of development and release that .netcore did.